# Android studio open app when new activity is started

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, alarmmanager

What i'm trying to do is this:
Make an alarm app, when the alarmmanager activates, switch to a new activity and open the app (The activity where you can stop the alarm)

What happens now with my code is this:
Alarmmanager goes off, it switches to the new activity but the app does not open. You have to open in manually to see the stop alarm screen. How do i do this?

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TimePicker klok = findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        klok.setIs24HourView(true);
        final Button getTimeBtn = findViewById(R.id.getTimeBtn);
        final TextView showText = findViewById(R.id.showText);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivation.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


        getTimeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int uur = klok.getHour();
                int minuut = klok.getMinute();
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, uur);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuut);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), "Alarm gaat om " + uur + ":" + minuut,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


                showText.setText(Integer.toString(uur) + ':' + Integer.toString(minuut));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

AlarmActivation.java

```
public class AlarmActivation extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("alarmact", "voor de service");
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(alarmIntent);

    }
}
```

MainActivity2.java

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wekkerapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application


        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmActivation"></receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".WekkerService"
            android:enabled="true"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope someone can help me a little with this

Comment: I don't know which api do you test, but there are some restrictions. From android oreo (api 26) you cannot display activity over lock screen, but your activity should open (you will see it after screen unlock). And from android 10 (api 29) you cannot open activity if your application is in the background, [here's](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) article about this.

Comment: @grabarz121 Hi! thanks for letting me know, how come the alarm app i use in my daily life is allowed to show over the lock screen and open when in the background? I run android 10 myself so according to that logic my alarm app isn't allowed to open an activity when my phone is sleeping. Maybe i dont understand the article enough?

Comment: I don't know. Google says there is possible to make an full screen notification, but I didn't check this. Use notofications instead an activity sounds good, to disable it you can create your own notification with custom view. One issue may be only, when user will turn off notifications for app, but it is user problem, not dev :)

Answer (score 0):

How about make BroadcastReceiver in your MainActivity2 ?

like this.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String BROAD_TAG = "braodTag";    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BROAD_TAG));
        }

public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent != null) {
                if (isRunningActivity) {
                    //get Data from intent if you need 

                }
            }
        }
    };
    }
```

and when you send Data, (AlarmActivation.java)

```
public class AlarmActivation extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("alarmact", "voor de service");
        Intent braodintent = new Intent(MainActivity2.BROAD_TAG);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(braodintent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, when i try this solution LocalBroadcastmanager is deprecated :/

Comment: Oh. my code is AndriodX-1.1.0. maybe you have to use LiveData

Comment: Im relatively new to android studio and java, how would i use livedata in your example?

Comment: this site will help you. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata?hl=en